# How can create multi table side by side using fpdf

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, html-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA2Gx.jpg)

Sir, I am using the  fpdf. I want two table side by side . please help me . How can able do the work more fast .